# Dividing a DoubleTensor matrix by a DoubleTensor number in torch

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to update a matrix of real valued numbers in a for loop using `torch.Tensor`.
Here is what I'd like to do:

```
-- W and P are of size NxN, r is of size N
delta_W = P * r:view(N, 1) * r:view(1, N) * P  -- this is an NxN
denominator = 1 + r:view(1, N) * P * r:view(N, 1)  -- this is a number
delta_W = delta_w / denominator  -- ## THIS ONE RAISES ERROR ##
W = W + delta_W
```

Just to be clear:

```
denom             -> [torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x1]
P, delta_W, W     -> [torch.DoubleTensor of size 200x200]
```

The error when I do the division is:

```
bad argument #2 to '?' (number expected at /usr/local/torch/pkg/torch/generic/TensorOperator.c:145)
```

I'm a heavy numpy users so I thought "broadcasting" was the issue, therefore I tried simulating it through `torch.repeatTensor(denom, N, N)`  with no luck. If denom is just a number (not a `DoubleTensor`) everything works fine anyway. Using the element doesn't work either, `delta_P / denom[1]` gives the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I tried using

```
denominator = (1 + r:view(1, N) * P * r:view(N, 1)):apply(function(x) return x^(-1) end)
delta_w = delta_w * torch.repeatTensor(denominator, N, N)
```

which doesn't throw an error but the results are wrong. To see this, try the following:

```
torch.linspace(0, 3, 4):view(2, 2) * torch.Tensor(2, 2):fill(0.5)
```

Comment: I have the feeling a smart use of `map`, `map2` or `apply` will do the trick but still haven't figured out how.

Comment: one of the reasons why I ran into issues is written [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md) and is related to overloaded operators. From the doc:"It is possible to use basic mathematical operators like +, -, /, * and % with Tensors. These operators are provided as a convenience. [...] Another important point to note is that these operators are only overloaded when the first operand is a Tensor. For example, this will NOT work: `x = 5 + torch.rand(3)`".

Answer (score 0):

I managed by using `apply`, `repeatTensor` and finally `cmul` for element-wise multiplication

```
rPr = r:view(1, N) * P * r:view(N, 1)
denominator = (1 + rPr):apply(function(x) return x^(-1) end)
delta_w:cmul(torch.repeatTensor(denominator, N, N))
```

though I wonder if this can be transferred to GPU with cutorch.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `denominator[1][1]`, you will get a 'number' instead of a 'torch.Tensor'. Then you can just write the division statement normally.

```
-- W and P are of size NxN, r is of size N
delta_W = P * r:view(N, 1) * r:view(1, N) * P  -- this is an NxN
denominator = 1 + r:view(1, N) * P * r:view(N, 1)  -- this is a 1x1
delta_W = delta_w / denominator[1][1]
W = W + delta_W
```

By the way, in the 1st statement did you want one of the P matrices transposed (`P:t()`)?